# Air ticket compensation for changed flight

Tags: air-travel, airlines, eu-citizens, delays, disputes

The departure time for my flight from Vienna to Lisbon (TAP) was changed from 13h15 to 18h30 (also the flight number changed). I was informed 2 days before departure about this by text message, but no reason was mentioned.

Does this situation count as a delayed flight (5h15 late) and am I entitled for any compensation (e.g. miles, discount on next flight, etc...)?

If the latter, where in Portugal should I apply for a compensation?

Comment: Yes, your situation seem to indicate you can collect compensation from your fellow travelers.  You'll have to file a claim with the airline to get a determination.

Comment: @Johns-305 please don’t post the answer in the comments

Comment: @Johns-305 - How does compensation from your fellow travelers work?  You pass the hat and there's some kind of EU law that they have to put in some money?  That's insanely messed up!

Comment: @davidbak The airline has to get the money from somewhere.  It's either through higher fares or reduced employee benefits.  Financially, it's actually good for the airline's management since the higher fares to cover compensation claims allow them to report higher revenue.

Comment: @Johns-305 - I thought I was making fun of a typo but I see you've brought an economist's POV to the question!  (Quite properly, too, it's just somewhat more abstract than I'm used to on stackexchange...)

Comment: @davidbak I don't see the economists' POV here. (1) To some extent, depending on conditions (including elasticity), the costs are borne by the company owners. You don't think a decrease in fuel prices gets passed to customers and employees 1:1, do you? (2) The company bottom line is negatively affected, since it is likely that compensation paid exceeds revenue generated from fare increases. Top line will go up, and too many people will pay attention to that, but...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are eligible for comensation under the European Union's [EU261](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004) compensation rules.

Your flight would classify as a "type 2" flight, which for a cancellation occurring less than 1 week before departure, resulting in an arrival delay of more than 3 hours, would be due €400 compensation, paid in cash (ie, not vouchers/discounts/etc).

You should contact the airline themselves to request this compensation.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've been looking into flight categories, https://www.distance.to/LIS/VIE states 2305km, so it should qualify for category2?

Comment: You're right!  I was looking at miles, not KM.

Comment: I also found these guys: https://www.flightright.co.uk/. have you had any experience with them?

Comment: I would suggest talking to the airline first.  This is a very simple case, and they will likely pay without issues.  If you use a 3rd party company they will take a cut of the payment (>25% in the case of the one you listed)

Comment: I've just done as you said, TAP has a quite top-notch website and it was easy to claim the issue, lets see how they answer, will let you know, thanks for your help...

Comment: so far I re-submitted the claim 3 times, over half a year has gone by, looks like their tactics is to "sit me out". I have never got any kind of answer from the carrier!

Comment: After nearly one year, TAP called me one day and offered me 600€ in voucher instead of 400€ cash, usable for reservations within 365 days. Happy :)

Comment: @vickel Good result, although if you'd prefer the cash they are required by law to pay it (but obviously only 400 euro).  I'll send you my address for my 10% cut either way :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your original flight was cancelled and your re-routed flight was delayed for more than 3 hours at the arrival airport.

In your case, the flight distance from Vienna to Lisbon is between 1500 and 3500 km. So, you are eligible to claim 400 euros as compensation from airlines as per EC Regulation 261/2004.

For more details about your air passenger rights and EC Regulation you can read here: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32004R0261:en:HTML

Comment: Does this answer add anything over the existing one by Doc from 7 months ago?